# RStudio Crashes When Plotting

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, plot, rstudio

For some reason, R keeps getting stuck whenever I try to plot something. Neither ggplot or base R is working, and I've tried this in both RStudio and R. I do not receive an error message, but when I run code like the code below, the command just runs endlessly and I end up having to terminate the session.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
hist(x)
```

Here are the technical details:
R version 4.1.2 "Bird Hippie"
OS: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

I've tried `dev.off()`, which isn't really a solution to my problem. Does anyone have any clue what's going on?

I tried running the code in both R and RStudio and get the same result. R just runs endlessly with no output or error message.

Comment: Was R installed in a non-standard way? Perhaps an important underlying library (cairo?) is missing. In R Studio try this, go to Tools, Global Options, General, graphics (right side, top middle tab), and try a different 'back end' graphics device.

Comment: @M.Viking Changing that setting to AGG seems to work! For some reason, using Cairo or Cairo PNG produces what seems like a memory error: `Error : C stack usage 7955720 is too close to the limit` and Quartz reproduces the same problem I had originally.

Comment: I use AGG also.